# Accessing logs of TFS builds via script or folders

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

We'd like to build a script that checks for certain output in the build log, analyzes it and sends results to the person in charge.

**What would be the best way to access the logs?**

**Is there any property that points us to the location of the log file so we could perform this step in the post-build step?**

Can we copy the log via the build definition or manually in the post-build step to some folder?

Right now we're stuck getting access to the log file of completed builds at all -
except manually via the web interface or in VS..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running a drop folder as part of your build the log files will be dropped their, the path will always be.

> DropLocation\BuildName\Build\logs
> [image: buildlogs]

So you can work out where the log file will be created and use the DropLocation property to identify the path (`Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Activities.Extensions.WellKnownEnvironmentVariables.DropLocation` in TFS2013)